# How to write a log file like system.log in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want my Mac Os X sandboxed application to write a log file of every action it takes, I think the correct path would be /Users/MyName/Library/Containers/com.me_developer.myAppID/Data/Library/Logs/. I know how to write a file a append text to it, but what I am looking for is to have old log files archived in a manner similar to system log files are written in /var/log , once they reach a certain size, they are renamed, and compressed (bz2). I wonder if Mac Os X or its lower levels UNIX offers a built in solution for that, and so I wouldn't have to write manually all the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [asl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html), which is the API for interacting with the system log facility in Mac OS X (and iOS). It's a bit low level, in that it's a C API, but it should do everything you want and does so in an Apple-sanctioned, sandboxing-compatible way.

There are a number of third-party, open source Objective-C wrappers for ASL. Here are a few examples (I haven't used any of these, myself):

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/ASLogger
https://github.com/billgarrison/SOLogger
https://github.com/nloko/NLOSyslog

Here's a couple articles/tutorials about using ASL:

http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-01-20/why-asl
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/

Finally, be sure to take a look at [Cocoa Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack), which is a very popular Cocoa logging library.

Comment: I would make looking at Cocoa Lumberjack the first - it is easy to use it looks like calling NSLog but writes to files or asl